# INNER JOIN using a CASE statements

Tags: sql, join, left-join, case, inner-join

I am trying to JOIN two tables and use CASE statements but, I'm not getting the results I want.

Here is my existing code:

```
 SELECT i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName, 
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 1 THEN 'Step0.5' END AS 'Step0.5', 
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 2 THEN 'StepI' END AS 'StepI',
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 4 THEN 'StepI.D' END AS 'StepI.D',
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 5 THEN 'StepII.1' END AS 'StepII.1',
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 6 THEN 'StepII.5' END AS 'StepII.5',
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 7 THEN 'StepII.D' END AS 'StepII.D',
        CASE WHEN [StepID] = 8 THEN 'StepIII.1' END AS 'StepIII.1'  
   FROM RD.dbo.vwProvider as l 
   INNER JOIN [RD].[dbo].[vwSteps] i 
     ON l.ProviderID = i.ProviderID 
   Group by i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName, [StepID] 
   ORDER BY FacilityName
```

Here are my current results:

```
ProviderID  FacilityName Step0.5  StepI StepI.D StepII.1    StepII.5 StepII.D   StepIII.1

4           This Is Us   Step0.5  NULL   NULL     NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL
4           This Is Us   NULL     NULL   StepI.D  NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL
6           Almost       NULL     NULL   NULL     StepII.1  NULL      NULL      NULL
6           Almost       NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL      NULL      StepII.D  NULL
6           Almost       NULL     StepI  NULL     NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL
```

Here are the results I am looking for:

```
ProviderID  FacilityName Step0.5  StepI  StepI.D   StepII.1 StepII.5  StepII.D  StepIII.1

4           This Is Us   Step0.5  NULL   StepI.D  NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL
6           Almost       NULL     StepI  NULL     StepII.1  NULL      StepII.D  NULL
```

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate using `MAX()` or `MIN()`, and it seems you do not need `StepID` in `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName, 
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 1 THEN 'Step0.5'   END) AS 'Step0.5', 
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 2 THEN 'StepI'     END) AS 'StepI',
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 4 THEN 'StepI.D'   END) AS 'StepI.D',
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 5 THEN 'StepII.1'  END) AS 'StepII.1',
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 6 THEN 'StepII.5'  END) AS 'StepII.5',
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 7 THEN 'StepII.D'  END) AS 'StepII.D',
        max(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 8 THEN 'StepIII.1' END) AS 'StepIII.1'  
   FROM RD.dbo.vwProvider as l INNER JOIN [RD].[dbo].[vwSteps] i ON l.ProviderID = i.ProviderID 
      Group by i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName
      ORDER BY FacilityName
```

Comment: What happens when there are multiple matches for `Step0.5`?

Comment: @Raj More If there are multiple matches for Step0.5, it will be aggregated in one row

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `StepId` from the `GROUP BY` and introduce aggregation functions:

```
 SELECT i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 1 THEN 'Step0.5') END AS 'Step0.5', 
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 2 THEN 'StepI' END) AS 'StepI',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 4 THEN 'StepI.D' END) AS 'StepI.D',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 5 THEN 'StepII.1' END) AS 'StepII.1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 6 THEN 'StepII.5' END) AS 'StepII.5',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 7 THEN 'StepII.D' END) AS 'StepII.D',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [StepID] = 8 THEN 'StepIII.1' END) AS 'StepIII.1'  
   FROM RD.dbo.vwProvider  l INNER JOIN
        [RD].[dbo].[vwSteps] i 
        ON l.ProviderID = i.ProviderID 
   Group by i.[ProviderID], l.FacilityName
   ORDER BY FacilityName
```